# Need to parse XML with a strange looking Schema

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, schema

As I understood it before taking this job, XML Uses a series of key-value pairs that up till today seemed fairly straight forward with how I was using it.  Basically I need to parse an XML document like this in Android:

```
<MailingAddress Caption="Mailing Address" PropertyType="CRM.Address" FieldType="4" DisplayType="0" ValueType="0" IsRequired="False">
<CRM.Address>
  <Street Caption="Street" PropertyType="System.String" FieldType="1" DisplayType="1" ValueType="1" MaxDataLength="400" IsRequired="False" />
  <City Caption="City" PropertyType="System.String" FieldType="1" DisplayType="1" ValueType="1" MaxDataLength="400" IsRequired="False" />
  <State Caption="State" PropertyType="System.String" FieldType="1" DisplayType="1" ValueType="1" MaxDataLength="200" IsRequired="False" />
  <PostalCode Caption="Postal Code" PropertyType="System.String" FieldType="1" DisplayType="1" ValueType="1" MaxDataLength="100" IsRequired="False" />
  <Country Caption="Country" PropertyType="System.String" FieldType="1" DisplayType="1" ValueType="1" MaxDataLength="200" IsRequired="False" />
</CRM.Address>
```

Does anyone know how I might go about parsing this or know of a parser that would be useful to me?  Am I going to have to write my own parser?

Comment: what library are you using?  This looks like well-formed XML and should be parsable by any common library...

Comment: Maybe I'm too new to using XML to see.  I'm open to using any library applicable to Android development.  I was looking over examples at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/ where they go over SAX, DOM, and Pull Parsers, but I don't think the way they are formatted would work with the XML I have to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like well formed xml , so have a schema, generate POJO using xsd to java command , and de-serilize then we should have values in xml as POJO thus we can do whatever we want from  java pojo